# CloudFormation Parameter Dynamic Regex

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a a CloudFormation template with 2 parameters. I want to set an AllowedPattern value for the 2nd parameter such that its regex is dynamically generated based on the value for the first parameter. Something like this:

`CloudFormation Parameters`

```
WebsiteDomain:
  Type: String
EmailAddress:
  Type: String
  AllowedPattern: !Sub '.*@${WebsiteDomain}'
```

`Allowed Input`

```
WebsiteDomain: google.com
EmailAddress: test@google.com
```

`Disallowed Input`

```
WebsiteDomain: google.com
EmailAddress: test@yahoo.com
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) for pre-processing of your template, before actuall deployment. Ohterwise, you can't do what you wan't.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudformation templates are not so dynamic, but you could write a script using the [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) which would allow you to write logic to check this yourself and then either immediately deploy it to the AWS environment or synthesize a CloudFormation template from the defined resources in your CDK app.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, No.  CF Templates are not that dynamic.